# Where do Metro bundler store the generated Bundle?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

Whenever we try to build RN app on XCode, a new instance of `Metro Bundler` will be running, I'm wondering where is the bundleJs being stored.

Reason for asking is, I'm wondering if the below command is unnecessarily

```js
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

**Steps taken whenever trying to release RN app:**

1 - Run the above command to generate the JSBundle file manually

2 - Archive the project on XCode

3 - Validate

4 - Upload

In shorts, Steps 1 seems to be redundant if Step 2 - `Archive` process will also kickstart a new instance of Metro Bundler? Or I actually got the wrong picture?

Comment: I know this question is old, but did you manage to find an answer? this is still the first and only result on google